# Iframe overlaps DIV in Bootstrap-Container

Tags: iframe, width, fixed

I have a problem to understand how to handle fix width in Flex-Container.
Here I have a 1/10/1-Grid and in the first column I need to embed an iframe. It should have
always a fixed width while the other 2 columns should be flexible.

How can I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
<head>
  <title>R24-Neu</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css?t=<?=str_replace(' ', '', microtime());?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
<div class="container-xxl mt-4" style="max-width: 1000px;">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 bg-info">1
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 bg-danger">2
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 bg-secondary">3
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 bg-info"><iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2702.2211736679656!2d8.531612115622265!3d47.36860157916956!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47900a0215fe7bc1%3A0xb1f301536e06dbe7!2sOberebenestrasse+47%2C+5620+Bremgarten+AG!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sch!4v1522527381540" width="250" height="180" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 bg-danger">b
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 bg-secondary">c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Big thanks for assistance
nullpunkt

I tried to set a css-width, but this ends in a wrap by bringing the other columns under the first.